# Why am I getting error when I run npm start in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why am I getting the following error when I run `npm start` in react?

```
C:\Users\ave\geekyShows>npm start
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ave\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ave\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ave\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-12T09_04_26_349Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. You should consider adding the contents of the debug log!

Comment: Two things can cause the error you're facing, one is permission and the other is that a particular file is missing.
You should open the .log file generated for you and go through it to be sure which one of those two is cause the problem and then you can ask a more concise question on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The directory you're currently trying to run doesn't have a package.json file. Maybe you're outside of the project that you just created. Happens to me most of the time when I'm working in hurry. :D

You can just enter inside your project directory that has package.json file like so (Assuming your project name as geekyShows):

```
cd geekyShows

npm run start
```

Hope this helps.